# MySQL - how to find most commonly occuring "tag" in a list of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Some context**
My goal is to get the "tag" that occurs most in a set of rows returned from a table (entities). An entity in my case is a group of famous people and their roles. I do not have flexibility to chage the database schema.

e.g. (quick SQL table strucT)

```
ENTITYNAME (varchar)
TAG1 (varchar)
TAG2 (varchar)
TAG3 (varchar)
TAG4 (varchar)
TAG5 (varchar)
```

example rows returned:

```
ENTITYNAME      TAG1            TAG2            TAG3                TAG4            TAG5
Warren Buffett  CEO             Investor        Philathropist       Billionaire 
Bill gates      Billionaire     Visionary       CEO                 Visionary
Steve Jobs      Visionary       CEO             
Oprah           Celebrity       Entertainment
```

**What am i trying to do?**
Get the TAG that is most common among SQL rows returned. For above example, i am expecting to get "CEO" (since it appears 3 times for the 4 record).
Assuming, a SQL query that returns n rows like above, how do i find the most occuring list of tags?

Please help, im not sure how to best approach this problem. I do not have flexibility to chage the database schema..

Comment: is the number of specific tag is calculated in the result or not? or you only look if exists in how much columns? and the repeat of a tag in a column should not affect the result?

Comment: the number of specific tag is not in the result- the result set returns all rows that have the term in tag1/tag2/tag3/tag4/tag5 fields.

Comment: yes, and repeat of tag in a column should not affect (the dataset actually does not contain repeats within columns for same entity)

Comment: Is this mysql or sql server?  Please only tag one DBMS.

Comment: this is mysql. will edit tag and remove sql-server

Comment: You are looking for a PIVOT query.  Unfortunately, mysql doesnt have a native method for it. (sql server does).   The alternative is to usually do something like what @ericpap has done with unions.  But if you google [pivot query mysql](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pivot%20query%20mysql), you'll find other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this: 
Make 5 unions like this:

```
SELECT Tag1 as Tag FROM Table 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Tag2 as Tag FROM Table 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Tag3 as Tag FROM Table 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Tag4 as Tag FROM Table 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Tag5 as Tag FROM Table
```

and create a view with it. Then:

```
SELECT Tag, COUNT(Tag) FROM myView GROUP BY Tag ORDER BY COUNT(Tag) DESC
```

The first Row is the most common Tag
Hope is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the `common tags between all columns` then use `join`:

```
select t1.tag1 as tg from table_name t1
join table_name t2 on t1.tag1=t2.tag2
join table_name t3 on t2.tag2=t3.tag3
join table_name t4 on t3.tag3=t4.tag4
join table_name t5 on t4.tag4=t5.tag5
```

but if you want `most common tag` then use a `count` with `UNION ALL`s inside a subquery

```
select tbl.tg, cout(tbl.tg) cnt from
 (select tag1 as tg from table_name
union all
select tag2 as tg from table_name
union all
select tag3 as tg from table_name
union all
select tag4 as tg from table_name
union all
select tag5 as tg from table_name) tbl
group by tbl.tg
order by cnt desc
```